# Is there a way exclude duplicates and closed questions in the question view?

Tags: feature-request, questions, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

On the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag, there are more and more questions that are closed as duplicates or otherwise. I did not find a way to create a custom filter to remove these from the question view.

Did I miss something obvious? Is this a feature that was previously proposed and rejected?

Comment: Does adding [`closed:0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%5d%20closed%3a0) to the search query work?

Comment: If you're talking about filters, the answer is no. My [request to change this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355243/323179) is on MSE.

Comment: @Laurel Apparently this _is_ implemented though, just not in the filter menu - you have to type it out manually. I posted an answer.

Comment: @Lundin It was not implemented for filters. That's a search, which takes a lot more time to set up and can't be saved like a filter can. Not all filters can even be converted to searches either.

Comment: @Laurel You can save the search URL as a web page bookmark in your browser though. Quite convenient for those using SO a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can search for `[c] closed:no duplicate:no migrated:no` then sort by newest first.

[https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[c]%20closed%3ano%20duplicate%3ano%20migrated%3ano](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bc%5D%20closed%3ano%20duplicate%3ano%20migrated%3ano)

As far as I know, you should be able to bookmark the above URL, then repeat for whatever other tags you may be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The network-wide [Stack Exchange Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) currently [only shows *non-closed* questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324083/241919).

Example: [Non-closed questions tagged 'c' on Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/filters/434062/non-closed-questions-tagged-c-on-stack-overflow)

However, while it can be combined with other tags (even from other sites) and also has an RSS feed, it is very limited in functionality:

- Only shows 100 questions
- No real-time update (though new questions will be highlighted after a browser refresh)